I try to use Tkinter and I get this error “Tkinter error Tcl wasn't installed properly”I realized that I don't have the Tcl folder in the Python files
I have been starting in python version 3.13 and I get this error (Tkinter error Tcl wasn't installed properly) and I have done the reinstall four times thinking that maybe I missed to activate this function although it comes by default.
I have searched the internet and this forum, and I noticed that when I open the location of the python IDEL file I have the Tcl folder and that folder does not appear. I want to use it in a virtual environment in visual studio code.
Do I have to install Tcl separately or is there another solution for this?
What am I missing?
I tried reinstalling python but I still get that error and I noticed that the Tcl folder does not appear when I open the file location from where I installed python.

Same issue has been asked several times recently.  It is a bug on 3.13 when virtual environment is used.

This is a bug in Python v3.13. For now, use Python version 3.12 or earlier.

Try this: py -3.13 -m pip install FreeSimpleGUI --upgrade It will dowmloading under Python 3.13. If you persist, then update Python 3.14.0a1
